# Javascript Open New Window And Write Content Again

Tags: javascript, window

I wrote a script in which when I press button first time, the window opens and contents are written. But second time I click on button, windows is focus instead of written content again.

Any Idea how to get rid of this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var OpenWindow;
function openwin(url) {
    OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin", "height=250, width=250,toolbar=no,scrollbars="+scroll+",menubar=no");
    OpenWindow.document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;url="+url+"\">");
    OpenWindow.document.close();
    self.name="main"
}
</script>

<button onclick="openwin('http://www.google.com/')">Open Window</button>
```

Comment: CBroe ? I don't get it what you are saying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwin(url) {
    OpenWindow=window.open(url,"main", "height=250, width=250,toolbar=no,scrollbars="+scroll+",menubar=no");
}
</script> 
<button onclick="openwin('http://www.google.com/')">Open Window</button>
```

Your main problem was setting the URL in the body, instead of using the proper method of setting it in the `open()`.